# Lambda expression for multiple parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I understand a lambda expression is in essence an inline delegate declaration to prevent the extra step

example

```
delegate int Square(int x)
public class Program
{
   static void Main(String[] args)
   {
      Square s = x=>x*x;
      int result = s(5);
      Console.WriteLine(result); // gives 25
   }
}
```

How does one apply Lambda expressions to multi parameters
Something like

```
 delegate int Add(int a, int b)
 static void Main(String[] args)
 {
    // Lambda expression goes here
 }
```

How can multi parameters be expressed using Lambda expressions?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You must understand the [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) behavior, where the last  parameter is always the *output* or *result*

> Func<1, 2, outPut>

```
Func<int, int, int> Add = (x, y) => x + y;

Func<int, int, int> diff = (x, y) => x - y;

Func<int, int, int> multi = (x, y) => x * y;
```

Comment: could someone elaborate, cant understand.

Comment: @Augustas  Func<int, int, bool> => (x,y) => x == y;   // this will return the true or false in the third bool variable in the func. x and y are the first two ints in the func.

Answer (score 15):

Yes.  When you have other-than-one (zero, or > 1) lambda arguments, use parenthesis around them.

Examples

```
Func<int, int, int> add = (a,b) => a + b;

int result = add(1, 3);

Func<int> constant = () => 42;

var life = constant();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delegate int Multiplication(int x, int y)
public class Program
{
   static void Main(String[] args)
   {
      Multiplication s = (o,p)=>o*p;
      int result = s(5,2);
      Console.WriteLine(result); // gives 10
   }
}
```