# Use List as parameter in a Func delegate

Tags: c#

I want to know if it is possible to use a List as parameter for the standard Func.

Example code (this doesn't work):

```cs
Func<List<int>, int> convert =
    (list_name) => x-2;
```

I just want to use a List as parameter in a Func if that is possible.

**E**: the possible duplication does help answer the problem. However in my question I want to know how to use a List and a Lambda expression in a Func. Do I have to foreach when trying to react with the list of is it possible to it with something else?

Comment: List with an uppercase L?

Comment: Sure, but your anonymous method doesn´t return an `int`. In particular: `x` is a `List<int>`, how should that be subtracted by 2? So what should that method actually do?

Comment: @HimBromBeere the x-2 can change. What I mean with that is that it also can be x*x or x*2 but the output is an int right so I have to use an int in the parameters from Func

Comment: "this doesn't work" isn't a helpful description of the problem, particularly when you then only provide pseudo-code - you appear to be trying to give a lambda expression with no parameters, but then `list_name` appears in a syntactically-inappropriate place... then we don't know what `x` is either. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Okay, so now that's syntactically correct - but what's x? And why are you accepting a list if you don't want to use it?

Comment: In short - yes it is possible. Use this `list_name` variable that you pass to lambda inside of your lambda expression.

Comment: The question is, how do you expect a *list* to be modified by an expression? When `x` is a *list*, how should `x - 2` or `x*x` or whatever work?

Comment: It works. It has always worked. `Func<List<int>, int> count = xs => xs.Count;`

Comment: in the List are a lot of 'int', all those 'int' needs go through the formula I gave it like 'x-2' or 'x*x'. So I thought about doing a foreach in the execute part of the lambda

Comment: @SupremeLeader: But your delegate has to return *a single int*. To put it another way - what would you expect the *integer* result of calling `convert(new List<int> { 5, 2, 6 })` to be?

Comment: So you want to return a `List<int>` also, not just one single `int`.

Comment: but all it has to do is to loop through the list and return the value

Comment: There´s not just *one single value* to be returned. You have *one* value for every elemnt of the list, so as many values as elements in your list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda expression for multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036584/lambda-expression-for-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Please show some sample inputs and sample outputs, and we can show you how to get from the input to the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want the delegate to be executed for *every single* element of your list. So you should also *return* a list of integers.

```
Func<int, int> f = x => x - 2;
Func<List<int>, List<int>> myFunc = x => x.Select(f).ToList();
```

Now you can call it:

```
var l = new List<int> { 3, 5, 4, 9 };
var result = myFunc(l);
```

See my [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/txfghj).

EDIT: When you want to provide the `x - 2`-part to the `Func` also you have to use a Func that has three generic type-parameters: one for your list, the second for your expression and the last as return-value:

```
Func<List<int>, Func<int, int>, List<int>> myFunc = (x, y) => x.Select(y).ToList();
var result = myFunc(l, x => x - 2);
```

Comment: And how could I use the func if the 'y-2' also needs to be in the func. Because I it's also one of the parameters but  I don't know how you name it

Comment: @SupremeLeader See my edit. You can provide any `Func<int, int>` into the `Select`-statement. Or you want to provide a func within a func?

Comment: No, not a func within a func. I want to know how to pass an List and a (I think called) lambda expression. So that the list goes through the lambda expression. I don't really know what you are doing with the 2 Func but I assume the first one makes the "lambda expression" and the second one puts the list through the "lambda expression" and put it back in a list. Sorry I am new to this. If this is not you mean can you explain it please.

Comment: A lambda-expression is nothing but a delegate that can be stored as a func also. So you want something like `Func<List, Expression, int>`, right? Than use `Func<List<int>, Func<int, int>, int>`.